# OSSIM In Production Environment

Tags: security, intrusion-detection, ossim

I am trying to get some real-world feedback on [OSSIM](http://www.ossim.net/).

Are you using OSSIM in production?

If so, what has your overall experiance been?

How many nodes are in your enviroment?

Finally, what kind of bandwidth are you monitoring?

Thanks!

Anapologetos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't use OSSIM in an enterprise, here's some feedback I read recently on whether or not OSSIM is "enterprise ready"

http://www.andrewhay.ca/archives/912

This was in a response to OSSIM's post:

http://www.alienvault.com/blog/dk/personal/is_ossim_an_open_source_siem.html

And yet another post related to the thread from Anton Chuvakin:

http://chuvakin.blogspot.com/2009/06/why-no-open-source-siem-ever.html

From what I have read in all of that, it would seem (SIEM?) the product has some potential but some analysts don't think it's there yet. On the other hand, Dominic at alienvault/OSSIM mentioned some examples of large enterprises successfully using OSSIM in their environment.

Hope that helps or provides you with some more information to chew on. Good luck!